# Changing marker size and color upon user input in Shiny with plotly (R)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I would like to be able to change the size and color of the markers in a plotly volcano plot upon user input. The user would write the name of a gene (Gene1, etc.) and the marker in the plot corresponding to the gene would update changing its size (e.g., to 20) and color (to yellow). Then, when selecting another gene, the previous marker should go back to its previous state and a new gene would be highlighted.

This is my try using `restyle`, but I did not get it to work:

```
# Simulate some data
set.seed(123)  # For reproducibility
genes <- paste0("Gene", 1:100)
estimates <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
metric <- runif(100, 0, 0.05)
contrasts <- sample(c("Contrast1", "Contrast2"), 100, replace = TRUE)
groups <- ifelse(estimates < -1 & metric <= 0.05, "Downregulated",
                 ifelse(estimates > 1 & metric <= 0.05, "Upregulated", "Not significant"))

# Create a dataframe
data <- data.frame(gene = genes, estimate = estimates, metric = metric, contrast = contrasts, group = groups)

library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Interactive RNAseq Data Visualization"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("selectedGene", "Enter Gene Name:", value = ""),
      actionButton("highlightBtn", "Highlight")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("volcano_plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Define your reactive data
  reactive_data <- reactive({
    # Your code to generate the data goes here.
    # For the sake of example, let's assume you have a dataframe 'df' that includes a 'gene' column.
    df <- data  # Replace 'data' with the actual data frame variable
    return(df)
  })
  
  # Output the plot
  output$volcano_plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      data, 
      x = ~estimate, 
      y = ~metric, 
      text = ~gene,
      type = "scatter", 
      mode = "markers",
      color = ~group,
      marker = list(opacity = 0.5, line = list(color = "black", width = 1)),
      hoverinfo = "text",
      source = "volcano_plot"  # important for plotlyProxy to know which plot to target
    ) %>% layout(
      title = "Volcano Plot",
      xaxis = list(title = "Estimate"),
      yaxis = list(title = "Metric")
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$highlightBtn, {
    req(input$selectedGene)  # Ensure a gene is selected
    
    # Access the current reactive data
    df <- reactive_data()
    
    # Find the index of the gene to highlight
    selected_gene <- input$selectedGene
    gene_index <- which(df$gene == selected_gene)
    
    # Make sure there is only one gene to highlight and it's in the plot
    if(length(gene_index) == 1) {
      # Calculate the correct index for JavaScript
      gene_index_js <- gene_index - 1
      
      # Restyle the plot to highlight the selected gene
      plotlyProxy("volcano_plot", session) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke("restyle", 
                          list(
                            'marker.size' = list(20),
                            'marker.color' = list('yellow'),
                            'marker.opacity' = list(1)
                          ),
                          gene_index_js
        )
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tried to use `restyle` to change the plotly upon user input, but it did not work. The graph does not change at all. I also tried `update`, but it gave a very strange behavior that I could not control.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to use `addTraces` and `deleteTraces` to add another trace to highlight the selected genes and to remove this trace when another gene is selected:

```
observeEvent(input$highlightBtn,
  {
    req(input$selectedGene) # Ensure a gene is selected

    # Access the current reactive data
    df <- reactive_data()
    df <- df[df$gene %in% input$selectedGene, ]

    plotlyProxy("volcano_plot", session) |>
      plotlyProxyInvoke(
        "deleteTraces",
        list(3) # Delete fourth trace
      ) |>
      plotlyProxyInvoke(
        "addTraces",
        list(
          x = list(df$estimate),
          y = list(df$metric),
          text = list(df$gene),
          type = "scatter",
          mode = "markers",
          marker = list(
            size = 20,
            color = "yellow",
            opacity = 1,
            line = list(color = "black", width = 1)
          ),
          showlegend = FALSE,
          name = "highlight"
        )
      )
  },
  ignoreNULL = FALSE
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked very well and I could adapt it very easily to my full code! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is some limitation to plotly with the highlight. Here I made it with ggplot and convert it to plotly.

```
...
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Create a reactive dataset based on user input
  reactive_data <- reactive({
    req(input$selectedGenes)
    selected_genes <- unlist(strsplit(input$selectedGenes, ","))
    
    df <- data
    df$highlight <- ifelse(df$gene %in% selected_genes, "Selected", "Not Selected")
    return(df)
  })
  
  # Output the plot
  output$volcano_plot <- renderPlotly({
    df <- reactive_data()
    
    gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x = estimate, y = metric, text = gene)) +
      geom_point(aes(color = highlight), size = 3) +
      scale_color_manual(values = c("Selected" = "yellow", "Not Selected" = "blue")) +
      labs(title = "Volcano Plot", x = "Estimate", y = "Metric")
    
    ggplotly(gg) %>%
      layout(
        hovermode = "closest"
      )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$highlightBtn, {
    req(input$selectedGenes)  # Ensure genes are selected
    
    # Update the plot based on the selected genes
    plotlyProxy("volcano_plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("relayout", list(xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(highlight = input$selectedGenes))))
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
}
```

This works even if u select multiple genes in the input, separate by comma: "Gene1,Gene2,Gene3"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works quite well, but in the full code (not this reproducible example), I have other functionalities (like using "plotly_click") that would benefit from keeping the plotly syntax. I am not so skilled with these functions and it I would not know how to adapt it to the ggplot code. Any ideas of why the limitation with highlighting in plotly?